# How to use an existing python script on multiple similar files and produce new separate data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing Python script, which currently ingests one Excel file. I want to adapt the script so that it ingests four Excel files and performs the same operation as the original script, but creates four separate data frames at the end - all named so that they have some semblance with their original input files.

So far it doesn't yet work. An error occurs in the part about file names: file_names = ["file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx", "file3.xlsx", "file4.xlsx"].

I am sure that it isn't right, but I am not sure what to alter.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
from itertools import product
import glob
import xlwings as xw
import openpyxl as op


data1 = {'Column A':[3, 17, 12, 142],
        'Column B':[20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Column C':['Year1','Year1','Year1','Year1']}
data2 = {'Column A':[192, 14, 11, 984],
        'Column B':[200, 221, 119, 158],
       'Column C':['Year2','Year2','Year2','Year2'] }
data3 = {'Column A':[2, 99, 41, 67],
        'Column B':[20, 25, 190, 187],
        'Column C':['Year3','Year3','Year3','Year3']}
data4 = {'Column 4A':[25, 919, 441, 672],
        'Column 4B':[21, 45, 100, 107],
        'Column 4C':['Year4','Year4','Year4','Year4']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)


df4.rename(columns={'Column 4A': 'Column A', 'Column 4B': 'Column B​','Column 4C':'Column C'}, inplace=True)


file_names = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

def ingest_excel_files(file_names):
    """Ingests four Excel files and returns a dictionary of data frames."""
    data_frames = {}
    for file_name in file_names:
        data_frames[file_name] = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    return data_frames

def perform_operation(data_frames):
    for file_name, data_frame in data_frames.items():
        numbers = data_frame
        numbers_copy_new= numbers.copy()
        
        numbers["New Column"] = numbers["Column A"] + numbers["Column B"]

def create_dataframes(data_frames):
    """Creates data frames for each of the original files."""
    for file_name, data_frame in data_frames.items():
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_frame)
        df.to_excel(f"{file_name}.xlsx")      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_names = ["file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx", "file3.xlsx", "file4.xlsx"]
    data_frames = ingest_excel_files(file_names)
    perform_operation(data_frames)
    create_dataframes(data_frames)
```

I am expecting/seeking four new data frames, each one with the name of the original data frame and "_new" ( I know that my script does not yet have a reference to this):

```
df1["New Column"] = df1["Column A"] + df1["Column B"]
print(df1)
df1_new = df1

df2["New Column"] = df2["Column A"] + df2["Column B"]
print(df2)
df2_new = df2

df3["New Column"] = df3["Column A"] + df3["Column B"]
print(df3)
df3_new = df3

df4["New Column"] = df4["Column A"] + df4["Column B"]
print(df4)
df4_new = df4
```

Comment: Can you expand on what error you get? Or how your expected output is different that what you are getting now? One potential issue I see is that you create a copy of the dataframe in `perform_operations` function which means the dataframes in the dictionary are unaltered and all the operations are done in the copy and lost when you get to the end of that function.

Comment: Suggest you to take suggestion from ChatGPT and try out various solutions